# React useState is setting wrong value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[image]

In parent js, I modify some params and it filters my posts array. Then for each post, I use post.js file. As you can see, useState isn't setting proper value, but If I use constant value instead of prop variable, it works.

So how can I make the useState working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using useEffect to synchronize your state with the props.

```
const [post, setPost] = useState(props.post);

useEffect(() => {
  setPost(props.post);
}, [props.post]);
```

The useEffect hook will re-run whenever the props.post value changes, and update the state accordingly.